# Infinite recursion with `enable_if`

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, template-meta-programming, sfinae

In an attempt to write a `wrapper` type for another type `T`, I encountered a rather obnoxious problem: I would like to define some binary operators (such as `+`) that forward any operation on `wrapper` to the underlying type, but I need these operators accept any of the potential combinations that involve `wrapper`:

```
wrapper() + wrapper()
wrapper() + T()
T()       + wrapper()
```

The naive approach involves writing all the potential overloads directly.

But I don't like writing duplicated code and wanted a bit more challenge, so I chose to implement it using a very generic template and restrict the potential types with an `enable_if`.

My attempt is shown at the bottom of the question (sorry, this is as minimal as I can think of).  The problem is that it will run into an infinite recursion error:

1. To evaluate `test() + test()`, the compile looks at all potential overloads.
2. The operator defined here is in fact a potential overload, so it tries to construct the return type.
3. The return type has an `enable_if` clause, which is supposed to prevent it from being a valid overload, but the compiler just ignores that and tries to compute the `decltype` first, which requires ...
4. ... an instantiation of `operator+(test, test)`.

And we're back where we started.  GCC is nice enough to spit an error; Clang just segfaults.

What would be a good, *clean* solution for this?  (Keep in mind that there are also other operators that need to follow the same pattern.)

```
template<class T>
struct wrapper { T t; };

// Checks if the type is instantiated from the wrapper
template<class>   struct is_wrapper              : false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_wrapper<wrapper<T> > : true_type  {};

// Returns the underlying object
template<class T> const T& base(const T& t)          { return   t; }
template<class T> const T& base(const wrapper<T>& w) { return w.t; }

// Operator
template<class W, class X>
typename enable_if<
    is_wrapper<W>::value || is_wrapper<X>::value,
    decltype(base(declval<W>()) + base(declval<X>()))
>::type operator+(const W& i, const X& j);

// Test case
struct test {};
int main() {
    test() + test();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's rather clunky solution that I would rather not use unless I have to:

```
// Force the evaluation to occur as a 2-step process
template<class W, class X, class = void>
struct plus_ret;
template<class W, class X>
struct plus_ret<W, X, typename enable_if<
    is_wrapper<W>::value || is_wrapper<X>::value>::type> {
    typedef decltype(base(declval<W>()) + base(declval<X>())) type;
};

// Operator
template<class W, class X>
typename plus_ret<W, X>::type operator+(const W& i, const X& j);
```

Comment: at some point the cure is worse than the ailment. Just bite the bullet and write 3 overloads.

Comment: Would be quite a pity if that were the case.  Oh well.

Comment: see my answer for 2 approaches

Comment: you've written more lines of code to work around the problem, i.e three simple overloads, than to do the simple thing. :) IMO, you are not really solving the problem, you are solving what *you think* is the problem, and these appear to be two very different things... ;)

Comment: @Nim well I could also argue that the OP wants to write mixed-mode arithmetica and *thinks* he needs to use `enable_if` and SFINAE magic, whereas old school operator overloading is all that is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an addition to the comment of TemplateRex, I would suggest use a macro to implement all overloads and take the operator as an argument:

```
template<class T>
struct wrapper { T t; };

#define BINARY_OPERATOR(op)                                      \
  template<class T>                                              \
  T operator op (wrapper<T> const& lhs, wrapper<T> const& rhs);  \
  template<class T>                                              \
  T operator op (wrapper<T> const& lhs, T const& rhs);           \
  template<class T>                                              \
  T operator op (T const& lhs, wrapper<T> const& rhs); 

BINARY_OPERATOR(+)
BINARY_OPERATOR(-)

#undef BINARY_OPERATOR

// Test case
struct test {};
test operator+(test const&, test const&);
test operator-(test const&, test const&);

int main() {
    test() + test();
    wrapper<test>() + test();
    test() - wrapper<test>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Boost.Operators makes this safer by using class inheritance to provide these operators

Answer (score 2):

This is something that is touched upon on the [boost page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html#htoc9) for `enable_if`, in an unerringly similar situation (though the error they wish to avoid is different). The solution of boost was to create a `lazy_enable_if` class.

The problem, as it is, is that the compiler will attempt to instantiate all the types present in the function signature, and thus the `decltype(...)` expression too. There is also no guarantee that the condition is computed before the type.

Unfortunately I could not come up with a solution to this issue; my latest attempt can be seen [here](http://ideone.com/CmJYbk) and still triggers the maximum instantiation depth issue.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to write mixed-mode arithmetic is to follow Scott Meyers's Item 24 in [**Effective C++**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)

```
template<class T>
class wrapper1 
{ 
public:
    wrapper1(T const& t): t_(t) {} // yes, no explicit here

    friend wrapper1 operator+(wrapper1 const& lhs, wrapper1 const& rhs)
    {
        return wrapper1{ lhs.t_ + rhs.t_ };        
    }

    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        return os << t_;
    }

private:
    T t_; 
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, wrapper1<T> const& rhs)
{
    return rhs.print(os);
}
```

Note that you would still need to write `operator+=` in order to provide a consistent interface (**"do as the ints do"**). If you also want to avoid that boilerplate, take a look at [**Boost.Operators**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/utility/operators.htm)

```
template<class T>
class wrapper2
:
    boost::addable< wrapper2<T> >
{ 
public:
    wrapper2(T const& t): t_(t) {}

    // operator+ provided by boost::addable
    wrapper2& operator+=(wrapper2 const& rhs)
    {
        t_ += rhs.t_;
        return *this;
    }        

    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        return os << t_;
    }

private:
    T t_; 
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, wrapper2<T> const& rhs)
{
    return rhs.print(os);
}
```

In either case, you can then write

```
int main()
{
    wrapper1<int> v{1};
    wrapper1<int> w{2};

    std::cout << (v + w) << "\n";
    std::cout << (1 + w) << "\n";
    std::cout << (v + 2) << "\n";

    wrapper2<int> x{1};
    wrapper2<int> y{2};

    std::cout << (x + y) << "\n";
    std::cout << (1 + y) << "\n";
    std::cout << (x + 2) << "\n";

}
```

which will print 3 in all cases. [**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a6411d6b37635e6012075396ed9a93e5-448233defdd967ed88c0e576473f7216). The Boost approach is very general, e.g. you can derive from `boost::arithmetic` to also provide `operator*` from your definition of `operator*=`.

**NOTE**: this code relies on implicit conversions of `T` to `wrapper<T>`. But to quote Scott Meyers:

> Classes supporting implicit type conversions are generally a bad idea.
>   Of course, there are exceptions to this rule, and one of the most
>   common is when creating numerical types.

Comment: Note that `wrapper<long> v{1}; v + 2;` will not compile because `2` is of type `int`. Maybe the constructor ought to be templated too ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. yeah, good point. If such conversions should be allowed, then a converting constructor template would be best. But I think in that case it's more convenient to use the mixed-arithmetic forms of `boost::addable<T, U>` which I think allows for that.

Comment: Indeed, that is what they are for.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't really work if the types are different: `wrapper<int>` and `wrapper<float>` cannot be added together.

Comment: @fzlogic but now you are expanding the scope of your question! for *fixed* `T`, conversion from `T` to `wrapper<T>` is straightforward, but if you want to also have conversions for arbitrary `wrapper<U>` to `wrapper<T>`, then it becomes much more complicated. For one, you will get a lot of ambiguities when multiple types are an equally good match. You would essentially implement the C++ type system with all its warts of implicit conversions and promotions.

Answer (score 1):

I have a better answer for your purpose: don't make it to complicated, don't use to much meta programming. Instead use simple function to unwrap and use normal expressions. You don't need to use `enable_if` to remove to operators from function overload set. If they are not used the will never need to [compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f593c3dc72aa890aed09869218eba23d-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51) and if the are used they give a meaningfull [error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1a98281781e36d96e641e1b9ce57e8d9-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

```
namespace w {
    template<class T>
    struct wrapper { T t; };

    template<class T> 
    T const& unwrap(T const& t) {
        return t;
    }

    template<class T>
    T const& unwrap(wrapper<T> const& w) {
        return w.t;
    }

    template<class T1,class T2>
    auto operator +(T1 const& t1, T2 const& t2) -> decltype(unwrap(t1)+unwrap(t2)) {
        return unwrap(t1)+unwrap(t2);
    }
    template<class T1,class T2>
    auto operator -(T1 const& t1, T2 const& t2) -> decltype(unwrap(t1)-unwrap(t2)) {
        return unwrap(t1)-unwrap(t2);
    }

    template<class T1,class T2>
    auto operator *(T1 const& t1, T2 const& t2) -> decltype(unwrap(t1)*unwrap(t2)) {
        return unwrap(t1)*unwrap(t2);
    }
}    

// Test case
struct test {};

test operator+(test const&, test const&);
test operator-(test const&, test const&);

int main() {
    test() + test();
    w::wrapper<test>() + w::wrapper<test>();

    w::wrapper<test>() + test();
    test() - w::wrapper<test>();

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

As an intersting additional information I have to say, the orignal soultion from fzlogic compiles under msvc 11 (but not 10). Now my solution (presented here) doesn't compile on both (gives C1045). If you need to address these isues with msvc and gcc (I don't have clang here) you have to move logic to different namespaces and functions to prevent the compiler to uses ADL and take the templated `operator+` into consideration.

Comment: This works, provided that the wrapper lives in its own, sheltered namespace ... a reasonable workaround, though not ideal.

Comment: @fzlogic: can you combine it with a `using w::wrapper` in the intended namespace ? I believe `boost` uses this private namespace trick for a couple of classes and then import *just* the class in an outer namespace and leaves it to ADL to pick up the right functions.